How to Clear Old Audio File Data in Librosa?
I am trying to process about 700 .wav audio files by converting each one into a spectrogram and saving it in .jpg format.
During each iteration of processing an audio file, I attempt to delete the data at the end. However, the RAM usage continues to increase after each iteration, reaching about 30 GB after processing around 300 files, which causes the system to fail.
Could someone please help me identify where the memory leak might be occurring and suggest ways to fix it?
FRAME_SIZE=2048
HOP_SIZE=512
DURATION=30
def save_and_plot_spectrogram(Y, out_dir, sr, hop_length=HOP_SIZE, y_axis="log", cmap='viridis'):
    plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
    librosa.display.specshow(Y,
                             sr=sr,
                             hop_length=hop_length,
                             x_axis="time",
                             y_axis=y_axis,
                             cmap=cmap)  # Set the colormap here
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig(out_dir, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
    plt.close()  # Close the plot to free memory
    plt.clf()    # Clear the current figure
    plt.cla()    # Clear the current axes


def process_signal(path,out_dir):
    x,sr = librosa.load(path,duration=DURATION)
    x_stft=librosa.stft(x,n_fft=FRAME_SIZE,hop_length=HOP_SIZE)
    x_mag=np.abs(x_stft)**2
    x_log=librosa.power_to_db(x_mag)

    save_and_plot_spectrogram(x_log,out_dir,sr)
    
    del x
    del x_stft
    del x_mag
    del x_log
    
def extract_sprectrogram_from_audio(source_folder,spectogram_folder):
    os.makedirs(spectogram_folder, exist_ok=True)

    for filename in os.listdir(source_folder):
        audio_path=os.path.join(source_folder,filename)

        audio_name=os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        #print(audio_name)
        audio_spectogram_path=audio_name+'.jpg'
        #print(audio_spectogram_path)
        output_dir =os.path.join(spectogram_folder,audio_spectogram_path)
        #print(output_dir)
        process_signal(audio_path,output_dir)


source_folder='/kaggle/input/audio-dataset/wav'
spectogram_folder='/kaggle/working/spectogram'
extract_sprectrogram_from_audio(source_folder,spectogram_folder)


The memory buildups are most likely because matplotlib keeps the figures you are creating around. But you should not be plotting at all when computing/saving spectrograms, just save the spectrogram data directly. Store it for example to a numpy .npy file.
If you for some reason must use an image format, that is also possible. Though you need to take care to avoid truncation, since those formats typically support 8 bit per channel. Ref How can I save a Librosa spectrogram plot as a specific sized image?
